# In a $k$-way set associative cache,main memory block mapping in range?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, memory-management, cpu-cache

> In a $k$-way set associative cache, the cache is divided into $v$ sets, each of which consists of $k$ lines. The lines of a set are placed in sequence one after another. The lines in set $s$ are sequenced before the lines in set $(s+1)$. The main memory blocks are numbered 0 onwards. The main memory block numbered $j$ must be mapped to any one of the cache lines from:
>
> 1. $(j\text{ mod }v) * k \text{ to } (j \text{ mod } v) * k + (k-1) $
> 2. $(j \text{ mod } v) \text{ to } (j \text{ mod } v) + (k-1) $
> 3. $(j \text{ mod } k) \text{ to } (j \text{ mod } k) + (v-1) $
> 4. $(j \text{ mod } k) * v \text{ to } (j \text{ mod } k) * v + (v-1) $

---

My attempt:

Somewhere it explained as : Number of sets in cache = v. So, main memory block j will be mapped to set (j mod v), which will be any one of the cache lines from (j mod v) * k to (j mod v) * k + (k-1).
(Associativity plays no role in mapping- k-way associativity means there are k spaces for a block and hence reduces the chances of replacement.)

> > Can you explain it in a formal way, please?

Comment: Read Inside the machine by Jon Stokes - http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Machine-Introduction-Microprocessors-Architecture/dp/1593276680 . Just the part about caches, you should be able to understand this. He explains it with pictures and most of these concepts are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Number of sets in cache = v. So, main memory block j will be mapped to
>   set (j mod v), which will be any one of the cache lines from ***(j mod v)
>   * k to (j mod v) * k + (k-1)***. (Associativity plays no role in mapping- k-way associativity means there are k spaces for a block and hence
>   reduces the chances of replacement.)

This is a simple concept of k-way set associate mapping.

To understand it better I would like to take an example:

**Example:**

- 2-way set associative
- 4 blocks
- Lines of a set are placed in sequence one after another (as in the
  question)
- The main memory blocks are numbered **0** onwards (as in the
  question)

Empty 2-way set associative Cache Memory :

```
╔═══╤═══════════════╗
║   │     Cache     ║
╠═══╪═══════╤═══════╣
║   │ Set 1 │ Set 2 ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 0 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 3 │   -   │   -   ║
╚═══╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Memory reference (data asked for processing) in the order:

4, 5, 9, 7

Reference 4:

4 % 4 = 0 (goes to Block 0 Set 1) **Cache miss** as it doesn't already present in the cache

As it had 4 blocks, we mod it the reference address to know which location of cache should I put it.

```
╔═══╤═══════════════╗
║   │     Cache     ║
╠═══╪═══════╤═══════╣
║   │ Set 1 │ Set 2 ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 0 │   4   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 3 │   -   │   -   ║
╚═══╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Reference 5:

4 % 5 = 1 (goes to Block 1 Set 1) **Cache miss**

```
╔═══╤═══════════════╗
║   │     Cache     ║
╠═══╪═══════╤═══════╣
║   │ Set 1 │ Set 2 ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 0 │   4   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1 │   5   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 3 │   -   │   -   ║
╚═══╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Reference 9:

4 % 9 = 1 (goes to Block 1 Set 2) **Cache miss**

```
╔═══╤═══════════════╗
║   │     Cache     ║
╠═══╪═══════╤═══════╣
║   │ Set 1 │ Set 2 ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 0 │   4   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1 │   5   │   9   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 3 │   -   │   -   ║
╚═══╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Reference 4:

4 % 7 = 3 (goes to Block 3 Set 1) **Cache miss**

```
╔═══╤═══════════════╗
║   │     Cache     ║
╠═══╪═══════╤═══════╣
║   │ Set 1 │ Set 2 ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 0 │   4   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1 │   5   │   9   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2 │   -   │   -   ║
╟───┼───────┼───────╢
║ 3 │   7   │   -   ║
╚═══╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

Visualization of Cache memory for you undersatnding:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                    Cache Memory                     ║
╠════════════════╤════════════╤═══════════════════════╣
║ Memory address │ References │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────╢
║       0        │     4      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┤ Cache line 0 elements ║
║       1        │     -      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────╢
║       2        │     5      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┤ Cache line 1 elements ║
║       3        │     9      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────╢
║       4        │     -      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┤ Cache line 2 elements ║
║       5        │     -      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────╢
║       6        │     7      │                       ║
╟────────────────┼────────────┤ Cache line 3 elements ║
║       7        │     -      │                       ║
╚════════════════╧════════════╧═══════════════════════╝
```

Both of the two set of cache line 1 is full, therefore calculation the location of first and last element of line gives us the answer.

Lets now check if the answer is option (1) as you mentioned

> 1. ***(j mod v) ∗ k***  to  ***(j mod v) ∗ k + (k − 1)***

Given:

v = 4 (four blocks)

k = 2 (two-way)

First element of cache line 1 = **(j mod v) ∗ k** = (5 mod 4) ∗ 2 = **2** yes, its located at memory location 2.

Last element of cache line 1 = **(j mod v) ∗ k + (k − 1)** = (9 mod 4) ∗ 2 + (2 - 1) = **3** yes, its located at memory location 3.

Done.

**Answer:** (j mod v) ∗ k to (j mod v) ∗ k + (k − 1)